# fading the map / adding a transparent layer in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What I want to do, is to display a simple google map (with basic, satelite and hybrid as options), add a custom marker to it, have it centered on a specific location, AND .. have the entire MAP faded out a bit so the marker would be more clear.

This last bit proves to be quite a difficult task, since I need to somehow fade the map, but maintain the marker and mapcontrols on top of the map, so the normal functions of dragging the map, zooming and clicking the marker would still work. If this was simple HTML, I would control it all using z-index values, but it looks like the markers are embedded inside the map tiles using canvases, so I'm really bound to using the google API to do this.

I've spent an entire day looking through Q&A here on stackoverflow, browsing the google API and trying to find some simple way to add a transparent overlay on a google map using API v3.

So far, the closest I can find about this, is to create a custom layer using KML and have it displayed as a control, but since I'm really not into how the KML works, this is really advanced, and I feel like I have to spend weeks to make this work correctly.

Is there really no simple way to create this transparency effect in a google map?

For simplicity I'm using gmap from smashinglabs.com, but I could easily switch that out with a more general google maps API call. This is the javascript-code I'm currently using:

```
$("#bmap").gMap({
  latitude: 'fit',
  longitude: 'fit',
  zoom: 'fit',
  maptype:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
  controls:[{pos:google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,div:$("#bmapoverlay")}],
  markers: [extraMarker,{ latitude:XX,longitude:XX,html:'',
  icon:{image:'*URL*',iconsize:[56,90],iconanchor:[28,90]}}]
});
```

Please note I've removed the long/lat numbers as well as the icon URL for the sake of privacy :)

Adding the DIV bmapoverlay doesn't work at all, and I would consider removing that all together.

Documentation for the smashinglabs gmap can be found [here](http://www.smashinglabs.pl/gmap/documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gamma` or `lightness` styler should work for what you asked. This is **not** a transparency effect, which means it will not allow to see any element that would be behind the map but it should achieve the *fade out* effect that you mentioned in your question.

See the [documentation about stylers here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyler).

Example usage:

```
var mapStyles = [{
    "stylers": [{
        "gamma": 6
    }]
}];

map.setOptions({
    styles: mapStyles
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/Lcay9e6n/)</kbd>

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. I think the gmap I'm using doesn't support setOptions, but I'm asking the developer about that. If it doesn't support it, I think I'll try to recreate the map using the general google API, although that might be a bit of work..

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Well after messing around for WAY too long, I finally found a working example of a map not using gmap but the general google v3 API. In general this map does almost the same, although instead of using gamma, it's simply setting saturation to -100 -giving a black & white effect which does nicely fade out the map. This answer is the closest to the solution I found, and I think it's the winner for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

1. I am sorry but there is no way to apply any sort of opacity on map itself that can visually highlight your marker.
2. Using KML is seriously a bad option. Using KML is very once you understand it but it will not fulfill your case. Furthermore, it will make your map slow. You can try it by using world kml file and using the following tutorial:
   *KML files*
   https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk#rows:id=1
   and
   https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1zn8cjdD6qlAFI7ALMEnwn89g50weLi1D-bAGSZw#rows:id=1
   sample code:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml
3. What I think will be best for your problem is that you create simple google map by sample code:
   Now you add one more div above map div and set your opacity/transparency to it. 
   Next you add custom markers using D3. Here is a great tutorial/sample code:
   http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711

If you are not familiar with D3, do not worry, code is very simple. (If you need any help understanding this code of D3, please ask). You'll be creating markers using SVG. 
Profit of using D3 for markers is that even if you place 1000+ markers on your map, it will not effect any performance.

4. Well you can also use custom style maps. Use following link and check on "lightness" and do modifications with it.

Regards, 
Suyash

Comment: This sounds really promising. I will check out D3 and see if it can solve my problem :)

Comment: I'm kinda stuck in the D3 documentation with the features I get from the smashinglabs gmap (auto-fit map and png markers). I think I might abandon this idea after all, even though it did look promising.